# UIPageViewController how to access invisible page

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using `UIPageViewController` to implement infinite horizontal scroll between pages with some data. Transition type is set to Scroll.

As soon as user starts horizontal scroll I'm giving back detail view controllers for previous and next pages via `viewControllerAfterViewController` and `viewControllerBeforeViewController` delegates.

And at any given time the pageViewController will have a scroll view and three pages inside this scroll view (I can confirm that using Xcode Debug View Hierarchy). How do I get access to invisible pages? `.viewControllers` property contains only one element corresponding to the visible page.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of the `UIPageViewController` is to dispose of pages not currently visible.  Its sort of like a `UITableView` but the cells are view controllers.  The only way to get access to the invisible vcs is to keep strong pointers to them after you build them (probably unwise for an infinite number of pages) or to build a particular one as you need it.

That should make you think about what you plan to do with an invisible vc.  If you're thinking about changing how it looks, think again: it doesn't exist.  Again, this is a little analogous to a `UITableView`, where we don't usually change cells directly.  Instead, we change our model and the cell changes because it is configured in reaction to the model in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:.

Same idea here.  Keep a model around that's independent of the page vcs.  When they get `viewWillAppear`, they can configure their views according to the model.

Comment: Are you sure it applies to the Scroll type of transition? What I was able to see by logging `viewDidLoad`/`dealloc` of page view controllers is the fact that `UIPageViewController` holds three pages to let user scroll left and right.

Comment: I ended up linking pages with each using weak references, but still wondering is there are better way.